# Resume abandoned downloads with php ftp?

Tags: php, oop, ftp, download, resume-download

Is there any way to resume a broken download via an ftp connction established with php? Can php resume a broken download?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can, using the optional $resumepos parameter of the ftp_fget() function.

Example:

```
$remote_file_name = "/test.txt";
$local_file_name = "test.txt";
$ftp_server = "ftp.your.server";
$username = "anonymous";
$password = "my@email";

$ftp_stream = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$result = ftp_login($ftp_stream, $username, $password);
if ((!$ftp_stream) || (!$result)) {
  echo "FTP connection failed\n";
} else {
  echo "connected to FTP\n";
}

if (file_exists($local_file_name)) {
  $resume_pos = filesize($local_file_name);
} else {
  $resume_pos = 0;
}

$local_file_handle = fopen($local_file_name, "w");
$result = ftp_fget($ftp_stream, $local_file_handle, $remote_file_name, FTP_BINARY, $resume_pos);

fclose($local_file_handle);
ftp_close($ftp_stream);
```

You could use the ftp_size() function to see if a file needs to be resumed or not, but it is not supported on all FTP servers so you'd have to check for that.

Comment: You use a wrong variable in your ftp_get. First you use $resume_pos and then $resumepos
It should be:
$result = ftp_fget($ftp_stream, $local_file_handle, $remote_file_name, FTP_BINARY, $resume_pos);